# date column is not sorting in ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ngtable

I have created an application using ng-table, The application is working fine, sorting is working fine except the date column, can anyone please tell me some solution for this. My code is as given below

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5U6zFH08YaIASayGsCZ5?p=preview)**

**html**

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in myValues">
        <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Last Update Date'" sortable="'lastUpdateDate'">
            {{user.lastUpdateDate}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.myValues = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, lastUpdateDate:"03/14/2014 06:21"},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, lastUpdateDate:"07/24/2014 06:41"},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27, lastUpdateDate:"09/10/2001 04:46"},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29, lastUpdateDate:"03/30/2013 03:31"},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34, lastUpdateDate:"02/20/2004 09:11"},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, lastUpdateDate:"07/12/2012 05:24"},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27, lastUpdateDate:"01/24/2013 01:11"},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29, lastUpdateDate:"05/02/2014 02:21"},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34, lastUpdateDate:"01/21/2001 03:31"},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, lastUpdateDate:"02/14/2002 04:21"},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27, lastUpdateDate:"03/22/2022 05:01"},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29, lastUpdateDate:"04/14/2020 06:11"},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34, lastUpdateDate:"05/03/2002 07:03"}, 
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, lastUpdateDate:"06/09/2000 08:01"},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27, lastUpdateDate:"07/10/2001 09:02"},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29, lastUpdateDate:"08/27/2012 10:10"},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34, lastUpdateDate:"09/12/2014 06:12"}];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        sorting: {
            lastUpdateDate: 'desc'     
        }
    }, {
        getData: function($defer, params) {
           $scope.myValues = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myValues, params.orderBy());
          $defer.resolve($scope.myValues);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Pablo this is related with ng-table

Comment: No, he's right - that's the entirety of the problem. [new plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/g7nQEyui8DndzYBXbsKp?p=preview) -- store the strings as Date objects and format them for display [using a filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: @AleMan I've just added a filter to the edit of Blazemonger, check what we [mean here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sqO7FFuCpdTlOwlLfanv?p=preview)

Comment: But how can we change it to date object....since the json with the date as string is comming from an external application and is not static like as shown in the plunker

Answer (score 1):

It works, but obviously not in the way you are expecting: There is nothing in your code saying that field is a Date, so the `lastUpdateDate` is being handled as a common String, so the order is alphabetical.

Comment: so what will i do in order to get it sorted like date

Comment: Perhaps if you stored `lastUpdateDate` as a JavaScript Date object instead of a string?

Comment: I found a very similar question with a good answer, so I'm flagging the question as duplicated

Comment: but the json with the string date is coming from the remote server

Comment: So fix the JSON after it's downloaded but before you pass it to ngTable.

Comment: How can we convert and fix it to date object....the json is not static in my application.....its comming from an external application

Comment: Just process it!, the callback function can parse the dates in a loop and store them as Date instead as a String.